# PowerShell script not deploying through Intune, would come back as successful however changes not seen

Tags: powershell, intune

I have been trying to deploy this PowerShell script to one of my test units however, which involves changing the taskbar layout in Windows 11 through changing the value of certain registry keys. When it does deploy through Intune, it comes back through as successful, however no changes were made. The script also is successful when done manually. There is something that I am missing but I can't figure it out.

```
$registryPath1 = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search"

$registryPath2 = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced"

$registryPath3 = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced"

$name1 = "SearchboxTaskbarMode"

$name2 = "ShowTaskViewButton"

$name3 = "TaskbarAl"

$value1 = "0"
$value2 = "0"
$value3 = "0"

IF(!(Test-Path $registrypath1))

  {

    New-Item -Path $registryPath1 -Force | Out-Null

    Set-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath1 -Name $name1 -Value $value1 `

     }

 ELSE {

    Set-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath1 -Name $name1 -Value $value1 `

     }


IF(!(Test-Path $registryPath2))

  {

    New-Item -Path $registryPath2 -Force | Out-Null

    Set-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath2 -Name $name2 -Value $value2 `

     }

 ELSE {

    Set-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath2 -Name $name2 -Value $value2 `

     }

     IF(!(Test-Path $registryPath3))

  {

    New-Item -Path $registryPath3 -Force | Out-Null

    Set-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath3 -Name $name3 -Value $value3 `

     }

 ELSE {

    Set-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath3 -Name $name3 -Value $value3 `

     }`
```

Comment: Are these current user registry entries?  That would only affect the user the script runs as, unless it were a login script.  You can exit with $error.count to see if there were any exceptions, or log it.  The user might have to login again as well.

Comment: The script works fine manually, it's just that through Intune it doesn't seem to acknowledge any changes. Tried this on a few units.

Comment: If intune runs as the system user, then it would only affect the system user.  You could try it as a group policy user login script, or if intune has something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is happening with your script, but here is an example of a script that we have been using successfully to apply registry changes to Intune-enrolled Windows boxes. This script implements the "Disable 'Allow Basic authentication' for WinRM Service" security change by setting a registry key. We use scripts like this in Windows Endpoint Manager Admin Center (Devices | Policy | Scripts | Add Script).

The script works by creating two new registry paths (that we found not to exist in our environment) and then adding the desired registry key. Previously we used -Force when creating the paths and did not check for existence, but we discovered that -Force drops and recreates the path, and that wipes out any other changes that have been applied within this node. The Get-Itemproperty command allows you to more easily confirm in the AgentExecutor.log file that your change has been implemented -- the output gets logged to this file.

```
$Path = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WinRM"
If (!(Test-Path $Path)) {
  New-Item -Path $Path
}
$Path = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WinRM\Service"
If (!(Test-Path $Path)) {
  New-Item -Path $Path
}
Set-Itemproperty -Path $Path -Name 'AllowBasic' -Type "Dword" -Value "0" -Force
Get-Itemproperty -Path $Path -Name 'AllowBasic'
```

In terms of finding out what the script is doing, have you looked in "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\IntuneManagementExtension\Logs" on the client devices?

In particular, the AgentExecutor.log file will contain the output from powershell scripts executed by Intune, and the powershell commands will generate text that looks like this when it is creating registry entries. You can also write messages to this file from your script using the Write-Output Powershell command.

```
    Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows
Name                           Property                                                                                
----                           --------                                                                                
WinRM                                                                                                                  
    Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WinRM
Name                           Property                                                                                
----                           --------                                                                                
Service
                                                                                                                
AllowBasic   : 0
PSPath       : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WinRM\Service
PSParentPath : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WinRM
PSChildName  : Service
PSDrive      : HKLM
PSProvider   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
```

We use these script settings in Endpoint manager:

```
Run this script using the logged on credentials: No
Enforce script signature check: No
Run script in 64 bit PowerShell Host: No
```

Other potential gotchas:

- There appears to be confusion online about *when* these scripts are executed. Our experience is that they are *not* executed except when machines are rebooted. That is the only time we have seen log entries in AgentExecutor.log indicating the scripts have run, and it's the only time we have seen the registry entries get created.
- If you change a script and re-upload it to Endpoint Manager, it is our experience that this change does get rolled out to assigned included groups. You will need to reboot one of the devices in the testing group, however.
- Be patient - we have seen delays of up to 10 minutes after a reboot before we see log entries in AgentExecutor.log indicating the script has run.

We have used this method to roll out more than a dozen different changes to 50+ Intune-enrolled Windows devices.
Hope this helps...